# How to disable panel drag in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, draggable, panel

I have created a component using panel. By Default it is draggable(using the title bar). How Can I disable the panel dragging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is weird cause the standard Panel component in flex doesn't move automatically. You probably used some customized version of it or used the popUpManager. If so check [this](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/08/16/creating-an-undraggable-titlewindow-container-in-flex/). Some code of your project would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Group Component and Place the panel inside with and height as 100%.
Then your panel Wouldnot be a draggable one.